# accessing the CSS in browser using question mark (?) in end

Tags: css, web-applications, webserver

can someone explain what is the difference in accessing `CSS` in browser by putting question mark `?` in the end and why the new CSS is not making any affects on Website.

I have deployed a new `CSS` on web server but its not making any affect.

I tried to open the URL in browser as below:

`www.mysite.com/styles/css/main.css`

and it loads the older version of `CSS`.

Then I tried it as below and it loads the new version of CSS.

`www.mysite.com/styles/css/main.css?`

After doing all this. New CSS change does not affecting the website. Its still displaying the old design.

Kind Regards

Comment: Short term, make your browser force refresh everything with CTRL+F5. Long term, fix how the server instructs clients to cache data.

Comment: @Jon  CTRL+F5 is not making any difference. I have cleared the browser cache manually as well. Thanks

Comment: @Jon can you please give me any idea to fix server instructs clients to cache data. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add something after the ? then change it when you change the CSS. What is happening is a browser will cache anything that doesn't change for a specific period, it does that by checking file names. so main.css? is still main.css? Anything after the question mark is a query string, generally it's used to pass data to a particular file. In this case it's just used to change the file string so the browser will update it every time it changes without affecting the file itself.

There are a couple of ways you can handle this, the first is manually changing the version, probably the easiest idea if you have a single header file, as in a template system that always loads the same head data.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css?ver1/>
```

Then on next change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css?ver2/>
```

If you'd rather do it automatically you can add a bit of PHP script to the css line like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css?time=<?php echo filemtime('./assets/css/main.css');?>" />
```

This is essentially adding a value that changes every time you save the file and results in something like this, the next time I save the file that time= value will change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/refficient/trunk/assets/css/main.css?time=1350305706" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you making it clear. Is there any way to sort it out in browser. I don't have access to the website source. I can only change the CSS. So can't change the html. I have tried Ctrl+F5 but not making any difference.

Comment: How can you access the CSS but not the HTML? Something isn't right here because CTRL + F5 should work (sometimes you have to hit it a few times in a row though).

Comment: Because website is a multi brand site and its running on third party companies server. we only provide them CSS to design it according to our needs. So I can't change the HTML. something is going wrong at their server or at my end. Don't known where its caching the CSS.

Comment: Any chance of getting them to update it with the PHP solution I gave you? It makes sense for them to do honestly.

Comment: @Hayer Have you checked typing the url of your css file and seeing the contents in the browser? DOes  it contain your changes? You can also try wget command if you are on linux

Answer (score -2):

browser cache is the reason,Adding ? after css is not recommended.Open your hosting space and clear cache and thread pool as well.